# using gradients API in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am reading about linear regression in tensor flow. Below is sample code.

```
n_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

X = tf.constant(scaled_housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0, seed=42), name="theta")
y_pred = tf.matmul(X, theta, name="predictions")
error = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")

gradients = tf.gradients(mse, [theta])[0]

training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
        sess.run(training_op)

    best_theta = theta.eval()

print("Best theta:")
print(best_theta)
```

to my understanding

```
dc_w, dc_b = tf.gradients(cost, [w,b])
```

above `[w,b]` is a list, but below theta is matrix of size for example of shape with bias is `(9, 1)` assuming first one is bias term and later as w1, ---w8.

But author is passing theta as `[theta]`, and not getting what output is calculated and how output will be looked.

My question is why author is using `[0]` in below line

```
gradients = tf.gradients(mse, [theta])[0]
```

I am not understanding what above line is trying to do. I looked at API description of tensor flow but not able to follow.

Kindly explain

Comment: gradients accepts an error function `mse` and a list of variables to get the gradients for and produces a *list* of gradients. So, you it might be more clear in next notation `tf.gradients(mse, [var1, theta, var2])[1]` or `d_v1, d_theta, d_v2 = tf.gradients(mse, [v1, theta, v2])`. When you want to pass just one arg you still pass it as a list and get a list with one gradient in return

Comment: all of `[v1, theta, v2, bias]` are Tensors with various shapes. Theta can be a 3d-tensor with sizes [3,3,128] and the gradient will have the same shape.

Comment: try adding print(theta) and print(gradients) to your code

Comment: @Selivonchy. Thanks for your comment. Sorry Still I am not able to follow. Request to briefly elaborate. I edited question with my understanding

Comment: Try my other suggestion. In short: [0] is used to select the only gradient in the list of gradients. the gradient itself is also a tensor and you can call [0] on it, but the author of the code never does it. theta and gradient have the same shape (9,1)